# Is there any difference between string.getLengh() and getLength(string) in Java?

Tags: java, methods

Consider 2 cases:

```
System.out.println(myString.getLength());
```

and

```
System.out.println(getLength(myString));
```

How can I create the method that uses after a dot notation like the first case?

Comment: Not in Java. You can achieve stunts like that using Groovy or Kotlin... Not Java.

Comment: The difference is that `getLength(String)` doesn't exist. You don't have to create the first method. It does already exist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The class(in your case `String`) has a set of methods. This must be known and can be changed in the source code of the `String class`.

As you don't have access to it(except if you e.g. create your own JDK/JRE with different methods or modify the boot classpath), you cannot change the methods of classes inside the standard library.

If you make your own class, you can create methods in it yourself:

```java
public class YourClass{
    public int yourMethod(){
         return whatever;
    }
}
```

You can call your method if you have an object of it:

```
YourClass yourObject=new YourClass();
System.out.println(yourObject.yourMethod());
```

[As mentioned by @ernest_k in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154806/is-there-any-difference-between-string-getlengh-and-getlengthstring-in-java#comment108188279_61154806) of the question, you can change the methods of other classes (you don't own) in some other programming languages:

> Not in Java. You can achieve stunts like that using Groovy or Kotlin... Not Java.

The second option does only work if you are in the same class or imported the method statically.

Comment: The second option doesn't work at all. There is no such method in the JDK.

Comment: @user207421 As I stated, you can theoretically modify the standard libs.